# curl with username/password authentication failed

Tags: curl

i try to get content from a website with

curl -user username:password https://website.de

also tried

curl https://user:password@website.de

but it fails.

- curl -user username:password https://website.de  delievers error:

curl : {"error":"Authentication failed: invalid or missing user/password or session cookie."}
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1

- curl https://user:password@website.de delievers error:

Invoke-WebRequest : Der Parameter "Uri" kann nicht gebunden werden. Der Wert
"..." kann
nicht in den Typ "System.Uri" konvertiert werden. Fehler: "Ungültiger URI: Es wurde ein ungültiger Anschluss
angegeben."

- curl -u user:password https://website.de delivers error:

Invoke-WebRequest : Der Parameter kann nicht verarbeitet werden, da der Parametername "u" nicht eindeutig ist.
Mögliche Übereinstimmungen:  -UseBasicParsing -Uri -UseDefaultCredentials -UserAgent.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:6

Can anyone help?
thx

Comment: the login endpoint for website.de is `https://my.website.de/index.php?rp=/login`

Comment: when i try running `curl --user username:password https://website.de` , i get a bunch of HTML, furthermore you are not hitting the actual login endpoint for website.de, so i believe you're NOT trying to login to https://website.de, you're trying to login to some other website, but you're not telling us what that website is. hence i have voted to close this question as "needs debugging details", for starter: it needs the website you are actually trying to log in to.

Answer (score 0):

thanks. That helped.
So now i can log in with

- curl -user username:password https://testrail01.ando.pay1-test.de/index.php?/auth/login/

Comment: it's a windows powershell

Comment: Hi Peter! It sounds like you solved your issue. Please edit this answer down to just the solution and create a new Question for any follow help you need.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).